# Block GeedoProductSearch using robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

i have robots.txt blocking user agent GeedoProductSearch but when i see logs i still see geedo accessing my page

```
 # START YOAST BLOCK
# ---------------------------
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 100000
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

User-agent: GeedoProductSearch
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Crawl-delay: 100



User-agent: Bingbot
Crawl-delay: 10000
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php



# ---------------------------
```

## END YOAST BLOCK

What can be the problem

Comment: _"but when i see logs i still see geedo accessing my page"_ - well it must at least access your robots.txt, to figure out whether you want to allow it access or not in the first place.